# Is there anyway to make this table fit within my document? Additionally, how may I space the first row of the table as the second image below

Tags: tables, makecell

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
   \begin{document}
      \begin{table}[H]
          \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
            \toprule
            String Tension & \makecell{Mean \\ Rebound Height} & Uncertainty in $\overline{h_{r}}$ & \makecell{Percentage uncertainty\\ in $\overline{h_{r}}$} & \makecell{Coefficient \\of Restitution} & \makecell{Percentage uncertainty \\in $e$} & Uncertainty in $e$\\
            (T) $\pm$ 5 N & ($\overline{h_{r}}$) / m & $e$ \\
            \midrule
        \rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
            147 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
           \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
            196 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
            245 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345 \\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
            294& 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
        \rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
            343& 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Processed Data}
            \label{tab:Raw Data}
        \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

I tried using the `\makecell` package, but I could not make it look presentable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: My Table Currently]

[image: Reference Table for first Row]

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: Sorry, I always forget to do the packages. Thanks!

Comment: Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902

Comment: Your example generates `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decrease the font using the `\scriptsize` command. Also, you can divide your table head into more lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}%[H]
        \scriptsize
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \toprule
        \thead{String \\Tension} & \thead{Mean \\ Rebound\\ Height} & \thead{Uncertainty\\ in $\overline{h_{r}}$} & \thead{Percentage \\uncertainty\\ in $\overline{h_{r}}$} & \thead{Coefficient \\of Restitution} & \thead{Percentage \\uncertainty \\in $e$} & \thead{Uncertainty\\ in $e$}\\
        (T) $\pm$ 5 N & ($\overline{h_{r}}$) / m & $e$ \\
        \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
        147 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
       \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
        196 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
        245 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345 \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{0.949,0.949,0.949}
        294& 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} 
        343& 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Processed Data}
        \label{tab:Raw Data}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It still exceeds textwidth.

**Note:** Trying to influence the position of a float by only `[!h]` or `[H]` is not a good practice. You may find a detailed answer related to this in [this TEX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/219947).

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, playing with the value of `tabcolsep` and the `\rothead` command from `makecell`. I also simplified a bit the code with the `\rowcolors` command  from `xcolor`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array, rotating}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}
      \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
      \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries\boldmath}
      \setlength{\rotheadsize}{3.2cm}
      \renewcommand{\cellrotangle}{64}
        \centering
        \rowcolors{3}{Gainsboro!60}{WhiteSmoke}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        \toprule
        \rothead{\rlap{String Tension}} & \rothead{Mean \\ Rebound Height} & \rothead{\rlap{Uncertainty in $\overline{h_{r}}$}} & \rothead{Percentage\\ \rlap{uncertainty in $\overline{h_{r}}$}} & \rothead{\rlap{Coefficient of} \\ \rlap{Restitution}} & \rothead{Percentage\\ uncertainty in $e$} & \rothead{Uncertainty in $e$}\\
        (T) $\pm$ 5 N & ($\overline{h_{r}}$) / m & $e$ \\
        \midrule
        147 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
        196 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
        245 & 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345 \\
        294& 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
        343& 1.345 & 2.345 & 2.345& 2.345& 2.345& 2.345\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Processed Data}
        \label{tab:Raw Data}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Rmano: Thank you so much for the edit!

Comment: You're welcome... It was just a missing apostrophe! ;-)